# I want to use JSON in Python to save users and password

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

This is diary writer with users login requirement. Now I need to save the users and passwords and be able to read them every time I rerun the program because not every time the user will create their account.

```
name=[]    
password=[]    
diary=""    
x =""    
namee=""    
passwordd=""    

file = open("user.txt","a")    
print("welcome to world!")    
while x != "q":    
    print("1) Enter :1 sign in!")    
    print("2) Enter :2 create new soul?")    
    print("3) Enter :q exit!")    
    x = input("what do you want?\n")    
    if x == "1":    
        namee=input("Enter your name!")    
        passwordd=input("Enter your password!")    
        if namee in name:    
            if passwordd not in password or name.index(namee) != password.index(passwordd) :    
                print("wrong password")    
            else:    
                file.write("\n\n\n\n")    
                file.write(namee)    
                file.write("\n\n")    
                diary = input("write your diary\n")    
                file.write(diary)    

        else :    
            print("can't find your name here.\n please create new soul!.")    
    elif x =="2":    
        namee = input("enter you name!")    
        if namee in name:    
            print("user name taken")    
        else:    
            passwordd = input("enter your password")    
            name.append(namee)    
            password.append(passwordd)

        elif x=="q":    
        print("thank you for your time")    
    else :    
        print("please enter valid value!")    
print("thanks.!")    
print(name,password)    
file.close()
```

Comment: So did you try that? What happened? Have you researched Python's JSON handling capabilities?

Comment: how can i saave users name and passwords by using json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get from a json file the information that you are looking to store (two lists), you can simply import json and load the file, and query it like a dictionary.

Imagine having a json like this:

```
{
    "users": ["Bacon", "Eggs", "Toast"],
    "passwords": ["Please don't do it this way though!", "runny", "buttered"]
}
```

One can simply:

```
import json

path_to_json = "./stackoverflowexample.json"

with open(path_to_json, "r") as handler:
    info = json.load(handler)

users = info["users"]
passwords = info["passwords"]

print("User 0 '{}', has password '{}'".format(users[0], passwords[0]))
```

This is a very insecure method of storing passwords, it is very inefficient, and you'll likely run into consistency issues at some point.

A much better method of storing passwords would be in a database, that would allow you to query for the information you wanted more efficiently, and to salt and hash the passwords when you get them so they aren't stored as human readable strings.

Example:

```
import sqlite3
import hashlib
import uuid

user_table_definition = """
CREATE TABLE users (
    username TEXT,
    salt TEXT,
    hpassword TEXT
)"""
add_user_sql = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{}','{}','{}')"

connection = sqlite3.connect("./stackoverflowdb.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute(user_table_definition)


# Add incoming user
username = "Bacon"
password = "This is a little better, but this is just an outline..."

salt = uuid.uuid4().hex
hashedpassword = hashlib.sha512((salt + password).encode("UTF-8")).hexdigest()

cursor.execute(add_user_sql.format(username, salt, hashedpassword))

# Check incoming user

username = "Bacon"
password = "This is a little better, but this is just an outline..."

row = cursor.execute("SELECT salt, hpassword FROM users WHERE username = '{}'".format(username)).fetchone()

salt, hpassword = row  # Unpacking the row information - btw this would fail if the username didn't exist

hashedIncomingPwd = hashlib.sha512((salt + password).encode("UTF-8")).hexdigest()

if hashedIncomingPwd == hpassword:
    print("Winner winner chicken dinner we have a live one!")
else:
    print("No access for you")
```

This is only showing you the lines that do the core of what you want, you should move some of these lines into functions, you couldn't call this code twice because the table shall already be created and other issues. For one, you don't have to use sqlite!

SQL is a really powerful thing to learn and considering that your question looks kind of like a hobby, I would recommend looking into as you go along. Best of luck.